# UPDATE many rows with different data

Tags: sql, sql-update

I have a table called name with 2 columns, `firstname` and `surname`. If I had 10 rows that had the `firstname` as TOM and the `surname` column was null (emtpty), how would I write an `UPDATE` command to update all 10 rows all with different surnames.

eg.

```
UPDATE [name] 
SET surname = 'value' 
WHERE firstname = 'Tom'
```

So where you SET the value of the column I would want to add 10 surnames and it would update the 10 rows with `firstname` Tom with the 10 different surnames I had in the update statement.

I hope I explained it ok and you understand.

Thanks.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Answer (score 0):

Create a table of surnames with id values from a sequence which starts at one.
You need one surname for each possible null value.

Set the sequence back to one.

Do the update,
selecting names with a NULL surname and
use the nextval to give you the id to join back to the table of surnames.

Answer (score 0):

You can update as many rows in one statement as you want. You can use a `CASE` expression to choose the value to write, or use a temp table, a table variable or a table valued parameter to specify the values to write. Use your favorite search engine to find out how to do that.